# .htaccess Manipulating the Query String

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

As per this wiki - https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewritePathInfo - it shows you how to change URL path into a query string:

```
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^/blah/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?  \
  /blah.php?arg1=$1&arg2=$2&arg3=$3&arg4=$4 [PT]
```

This method requires you to predict the exact amount, so if there was 5 levels for 5 values:

```
/blah/1/2/3/4/5/
```

Translating to

```
blah.php?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3&var4=4&var5=5
```

Is there a way to do this without pre knowing the number of variables, almost being dynamic?

For example, one day a user might enter 7, another day 1, another day 9 and the ReWrite Regex being able to handle them all?

Answer (score 3):

To make it completely dynamic you should not bother about breaking the PATH info into multiple query parameters. Just pass everything after `blah/` to your php file and let php do the split on `/`. So you can use this rule:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?(blah)/(.+)$ $1.php?path=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```